# Dynamic structure inside a dynamic structure in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, structure

How would one accomplish this? I know how to create dynamic structures, but is it possible to have a dynamic structure within another..? Say I wanted to have an invoice where a dynamic structure called Customer would include the customer ID, customer name, number of items, and then the structure for items which would contain the product description, quantity and price...

I'd appreciate any samples. I dunno, I'm at a loss and am starting to get burned out. Lets see if I can get a helping hand.

Thanks!

Comment: By "dynamic structures", do you mean classes?

Comment: No, I mean the data form. Like... 
struct foo {
...
...
};

Comment: In C++, a structure is a class defined with the struct keyword.[1] Its members and base classes are public by default. A class defined with the class keyword has private members and base classes by default. This is the only difference between structs and classes in C++. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes)

Comment: My apologies. Still pretty nub, its for my class.

Comment: If by danamic structure you mean you have a pointer to some `struct`(or `class`) and use `new` to allocate memory to that pointer, then yes of course it's possible. :) Just have a pointer member in the structure, and allocate just the same to that member.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I believe you could accomplish that with an std list. (And many many other ways actually)

```
class Customer
{
private:
    int ID;
    ...
    std::list<Item> items;
}   


std::list<Customer> customers;
```

Using a dynamic array of items:

```
class Customer
{
public:
   Customer(int size) : nItems(size)
   {
       items = new Item[nItems];
   }
   Customer(const Customer& customer) : Customer(customer.getItems())
   {
       memcpy(items, customer.getItems(), nItems);
   }
   ~Customer() {delete [] items;}
   int getNumItems() {return nItems;}
   Item *getItems() {return items;}
private:
    int ID;
    ...
    Item *items;
    int nItems;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, if only my professor would let me use things we haven't covered in our book yet... brilliant. I was going about it in pretty much exactly the manner this guy was. [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5385/) is there a way I could use new for the items structure inside of the customer structure?

Comment: Yes, but std::list takes care of dynamic allocation.
If you want to do it anyway check out the edit of the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to free/delete that upon destruction? In the dynamic case that is.

Comment: You still need the copy constructor and assignment operator in that case.

Comment: @NicolasArroyo: If you make dynamic memory management a private fact of a class, you should also define what to do for copy and assignment (orat least disable them), or an innocent statement like `a=b` between two `Customer`s will end in tears!

Comment: @KillianDS and Emilio, just trying to illustrate a simple point, but I added the copy constructor anyway.

Comment: @NicolasArroyo the simple point is that dynamic memory management should be avoided as much as possible, showing what you have to do to correclty implement even this simple thing makes that point even better. That aside, without copy and assignment operators your code is incorrect, even if it is a simple example.